# What packages are required to install C++ API on Linux Mint 17?

Tags: qgis, api, c++, linux

What packages are required to install C++ API on Linux Mint 17?
I already have access to the Python API (installed via “python-qgis” package), but no C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have to build QGIS from source on Linux Mint. See [Building QGIS from source - step by step](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qgis/QGIS/master/INSTALL) for instructions.

Comment: Thanx, you're right. And the source code could be downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/).